# 403 When Trying to list Nginx Directory

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to host a directory with style using nginx and fancyindex.  However, when I try to view a directory, I get a 403 error.  I can view files, if it exists, just not a directory without an index.html (and if it does have an index.html, it shows that instead of the directory).

I checked permissions on the directory, and the directory and all its contents are 777.  User is root (because it's hosted from a docker container, specifically image `byjg/nginx-extras`).

What am I doing wrong to get that 403 error?

My default.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html;
    server_name web.example.com;
    autoindex on;
    location / {
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        allow all;
        autoindex on;
        fancyindex on;
        fancyindex_localtime on;
        fancyindex_exact_size off;
        fancyindex_header "/theme/header.html";
        fancyindex_footer "/theme/footer.html";
        fancyindex_ignore "theme";
        fancyindex_name_length 255; # Maximum file name length in bytes, change as you like.
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error if you comment out all of the `fancyindex` directives? Also, check the access and error logs. Also, test that Nginx is reading the correct file using `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`)

Comment: make sure you are passing your configuration to inside the container. Basically you have to do `docker run -d -p /path/to/your/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf byjg/nginx-extras`